# Existence of high degree rational curve in Fano which also lie in a fixed proper subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth Fano variety of Picard number one. Let $Y \subset X$ be a closed subvariety. Let $d$ be an integer such that there is a dominating component $K_d$ of rational curves of degree $d$ in $X$. In other words, the family $K_d$ of curves covers $X$.

Question: For all such positive integer $d$, does there exist a rational curve $l \in K_d$ passing through a general point $p \in Y$ which lie in $Y$?

Comment: Who lies in $Y$ --- point $P$ (or $p$?), or the curve?

Comment: The curve. The point $p$ is on $Y$. There was some typo. I have corrected.

Comment: If the curve lies in $Y$ then $X$ is irrelevant for the problem --- you are just asking if there is a curve in $Y$ passing through $p$. Of course, this depends very much on the properties of $Y$. For instance, if $Y$ is a smooth K3 surface the answer is negative.

Comment: There's a typo in the title

Comment: Assume that $Y$ is unirulled. If $K^Y_d$ is a component of rational curves of degree $d$, then my question is equivalent to asking whether $K_d^Y \cap K_d$ has dimension at least $\text{dim}(Y)$. Is that always true ?

Comment: Please fix the typo in the question. I'm a little bit OCD about spelling errors and it's giving me anxiety. (The word degre should be degree, unless of course it's some other mathematical property that I haven't heard of. in which case, Oops!.)

Answer (score 2):

No, just take $Y$ the product of $\mathbb P^1$ with a variety with no rational curves where the $\mathbb P^1$ is embedded in $X$ as something of degree $2$, and take $d$ odd. The only rational curves in $Y$ will be covers of the $\mathbb P^1$ which have even degree.